# Node.js: Use an existing TCP Socket in a different proccess

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I'm developing a Gateway with Node.js and I'm having some issues. I have the following situation:

- A TCP socket (net module) receives a connection from a client, parses the message and writes in a RabbitMQ queue which is read by another service.
- This other service receives the message and sends a confirmation message to another RabbitMQ queue, which is read by a worker written in Node (rabbit.js).
- In this worker, I'll read the queue, parse a response and send it to the client via the previous TCP connection which is still open.

The problem is, I don't know how to reuse the socket already created (considering that the conection doesn't have any problems and is still alive)

Is there's a way to reuse a TCP socket in another proccess that way?

Thanks a lot.